# How to make a permanent alias in oh-my-zsh?

Tags: command-line, alias, zsh

In my .zshrc I tried to make a few aliases .I looked into a lot of places, but I couldn't find out a way that worked. I used this code below:

```
# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs, 
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh 
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder. 
# For a full list of active aliases, run alias. # # Example aliases
alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
alias n= "nano"  
alias m= "mkdir"
alias w= "cd ~/Documents/UoMWorkspace/Semester2"  
alias j= "cd ~/Documents/UoMWorkspace/Semester2/COMP17412"
```

Then I wrote a command `source ~/.zshrc`. Still it didn't resolve the issue. I get error messages like `zsh: command not found: j`

Could anyone help me with any suggestions and let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Judging from the (mutliple) comments and from the error I suppose each alias is actually set on a single line, correct?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

There must not be any whitespaces around between `=` and either alias name or alias definition:

```
alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
alias n="nano"
alias m="mkdir"
alias w="cd ~/Documents/UoMWorkspace/Semester2"
alias j="cd ~/Documents/UoMWorkspace/Semester2/COMP17412"
```

---

BTW: If you are looking for a way to shorten directory names, I suggest looking into *Named Directories* and the `AUTO_CD` option instead of aliases:

```
hash -d w=~/Documents/UoMWorkspace/Semester2
hash -d j=~/Documents/UoMWorkspace/Semester2/COMP17412
```

This allows you to use `~w` instead of `~/Documents/UoMWorkspace/Semester2` and `~j` instead of `~/Documents/UoMWorkspace/Semester2/COMP17412` (or `~w/COMP17412`). So `cd ~j` is identical to `cd ~/Documents/UoMWorkspace/Semester2`. It also works as part of a path, e.g. `cat ~j/somedir/somefile`.

With

```
setopt AUTO_CD
```

`zsh` will automatically `cd` to a directory if it is given as command on the command line and it is not the name of an actual command. e.g.

```
% /usr
% pwd
/usr
% ~w
/home/YOURUSERNAME/Documents/UoMWorkspace/Semester2
```

Comment: As a further explanation why not use spaces before and after the equation sign:e.g. `a = b`: This will be considered as a command `a` with two parameters (`b` and `=`) and will throw an error: `zsh: command not found: a`. If you put `alias`before that (`alias a = b`), it will be somehow similar.

Comment: Isn't that `AUTO_CD` cause your command history unreadable?

Comment: @nanono That depends on what you mean by "unreadable". By itself `AUTO_CD` does nothing more than allow to switch into directories by only using their paths instead of using the `cd` command. Of course, if you make active use of this feature, it is not easy to tell from the history whether the command `docs` ran a executable of that name or if it was used to switch into a directory named "docs".

Comment: Special thanks for shortening directories names - I have been looking for it